# ContentResolver requestSync not triggering SyncAdapter onPerformSync when wifi not available but cellular data is on samsung device

Tags: android, kotlin, android-contentresolver, android-syncadapter, networkmanager

The problem is as follows. I have a working SyncAdapter and ContentResolver setup. The problem that SyncAdapters `onPerformSync` is not triggered happens when I have wifi turned on but the wifi does not have an internet connection (it is connected to an IOT device). I have a sim card and cellular data is available. In the app I have NetworkManager set so I request cellular data like so:

```
val req = NetworkRequest.Builder()
req.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
req.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
```

And if I create an API request instead of triggering `ContentResolver.requestSync` it works normally.

This code also works normally on a Huawei tablet but not on Samsung.

So basically. I have cellular internet but SyncAdapter does not realise this(on Samsung device) and does not trigger `onPerformSync`. Anyway to make SyncAdapter realise this?